# Populating html from data object with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive me if this is redundant, I'm having trouble finding questions/answers that are using vanilla JS specifically.

I have a data object for store items I've created that I'm trying to display on the page but I only seem to be getting the first item in the array to appear, which lead me to believe I needed some sort of for loop related to the array length but I tried variations and I seem to be getting the same result (only the first item), or in some cases nothing at all.

I've logged out the HTML and the correct items are there in the console so its working and they are ready to go. I'm missing something.

```
feature = () => isFeatured.map(item => {
  // console.log("imworking");
  html = `
      <img src="${item.image}" alt=""> 
      <h2>${item.info}</h2>
      <h3>${item.price}</h3>
      <button>Add to Cart</button>
        `
  //console.log(html);
  document.getElementById('featuredItem').innerHTML = html;
})
```

I don't think the problem is the HTML because the one item is displaying fine but here it is anyways

```
<div id="featuredItem"></div>
```

Comment: How many objects do you have?

Comment: @zer00ne  in the array itself there's 20, but in this container there's only 4 because this container is only displaying items from the array that have a featured value of true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey sorry this is so late, hopefully you figured it out already! I ran out of room in the comment section so I'm throwing my response to @maxineheadroom down here. If I understand your question you want the img htags and buttons wrapped in a div? I would make a new function called `creatItem` or something. 

`` const createItem = (item) => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add(`item_${item.id}`)
    const img = document.createElement('img').src = item.img
    const info = document.createElement('h2').textContent = item.info;
    const price = document.createElement('h3').textContent = item.price;
    const btn = document.createElement('button').textContent = 'Add to cart'
    wrapper.appendChild(img);
    wrapper.appendChild(info);
    wrapper.appendChild(price);
    wrapper.appendChild(btn);
    return wrapper
} ``

then in your for loop you can just do 
`featuredItem.appendChild(createItem(item))`

Answer (score 3):

You're replacing the `featuredItem`'s HTML every time the loop runs. Also, you shouldn't use `map` since you're not mapping to a new array; use `forEach` instead. Also, make sure to declare all variables with `const` (or `let`), to avoid implicitly creating global variables, which should be avoided:

```
const feature = () => isFeatured.forEach(item => {
  // console.log("imworking");
  const html = `
<img src="${item.image}" alt=""> 
<h2>${item.info}</h2>
<h3>${item.price}</h3>
<button>Add to Cart</button>
`;
  //console.log(html);
  document.getElementById('featuredItem').innerHTML += html;
});
feature();
```

But directly inserting variables into HTML markup like that is not all that safe. It would be better to explicitly create and append elements, assigning values to their `textContent`, like this:

```
const featuredItem = document.querySelector('#featuredItem');
const feature = () => isFeatured.forEach(({ image, info, price }) => {
  featuredItem
    .appendChild(document.createElement('img'))
    .src = image;
  featuredItem
    .appendChild(document.createElement('h2'))
    .textContent = info;
  featuredItem
    .appendChild(document.createElement('h3'))
    .src = price;
  featuredItem
    .appendChild(document.createElement('button'))
    .textContent = 'Add to Cart';
});
feature();
```

Comment: probably wouldn't hurt to wrap your html in a containing div with a class name that is the item's id for ease of finding later.

Comment: got it. I see you used .innerHTML += html   versus  .innerHTML =  html. can you just elaborate on the difference there so I know for the future.

Comment: @maxineheadroom `=` replaces the contents; `+=` appends contents to the existing contents. Ie `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`

Comment: @maxineheadroom It's just like with strings; when you do `mystr = 'new str'`, the old `mystr` gets completely discarded. To concatenate instead, use `mystr +=`. `innerHTML` is just another string.

Comment: @JohnHooper (or CertainPerformance) one more question, how would I wrap the elements above in a parent div and add classes using create and append?

Comment: my response would have been too long so i just tossed it in an answer below

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are setting the innerhtml, through looping the HTML changes as well as the innerhtml.
You should have a container for string HTML generated by loop.

```
feature = () => isFeatured.map(item => {
    let markup = new Array();
    html = `
        <img src="${item.image}" alt=""> 
        <h2>${item.info}</h2>
        <h3>${item.price}</h3>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>      
        `
    markup.push(html);
    html = markup.join("");
    document.getElementById('featuredItem').innerHTML = html;
})
```

Also it can be than if you use appendchild rather than innerhtml.

Comment: ah, thank you for the ending comment regarding appendChild(), I forget from time to time that it is better just to set the innerHTML directly on an existing div, rather than making one and appending to it, then when you want to update the element, well in my case, was a pain. Cheers~